# PHP Oracle DB Function Errors

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I have been getting the following errors:

```
Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

So I have the following code:

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT p.id, m.display_name, m.updated_at, group_concat(meta.value) as value, p.path
                                    FROM metadata_custom meta
                                    JOIN page as p on p.id = meta.page_id
                                    INNER JOIN metadata m on p.metadata_id = m.id
                                    GROUP BY p.id
                                    UNION ALL
                                    SELECT m.id, name, m.updated_at, m.account_id, path FROM cascade_publish.file
                                    JOIN metadata m on m.id = cascade_publish.file.metadata_id");

    $stid = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$stid) {
                echo 'error with sql statements';
               }
        else{
            echo 'success'; 
            }
    //$r = oci_execute($stid ); 
    $xml_group_data_1 = "";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stid)) 
    {   
        $TimeStamp = $row['updated_at'];
        $ID = $row['id'];
        $URL = $row['path'];//need to figure this out
        $dept = substr($URL,6)."/"; //should find department
        $directory = substr($URL,6).".html";
        $URL = 'http://www.website.edu/$directory'; //should create URL to compare against
        $Audience = $row['value'];
        $Department = $dept;//set department = to $dept
            //properly set mimetype and filetypes depending on file extension
            if(strpos($directory,'.html') || strpos($directory,'.htm') || strpos($directory,'.htmls')){
            $FileType = 'HTML content';
            $MimeType = 'text/html';
            }
                else{
                    $FileType = 'Unknown';
                    $MimeType = 'Unknown';
                    }

        // for now just try inserting into wcm database during while loop
        $stid_check = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO WCM_GSA_FEEDDATA (URL,Audience,Department,MimeType,FileType,TimeStamp) VALUES (:URL, :Audience, :Department, :MimeType, :FileType, :TimeStamp)");
        // bind values to the parameters in the parsed sql string
        oci_bind_by_name($stid_check, ":URL", $URL);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid_check, ":Audience", $Audience);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid_check, ":Department", $Department);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid_check, ":MimeType", $MimeType);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid_check, ":FileType", $FileType);
                    oci_bind_by_name($stid_update, ":TimeStamp", $TimeStamp);       
        $r = oci_execute($stid_check);
```

Basically I was handed down this program, and had to change one connection to a mysql database and as a result I have been plagued with errors trying to figure out how to rewrite this code to support both an oracle connection and a mysql connection. Before the code only used a single oracle connection. Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You didn't bind the timestamp

Comment: Binded the timestamp, now i get Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): 7 is not a valid oci8 statement resource on the line where i binded the timestamp

Comment: Why did you bind the timestamp to `$stid_update` ?

Comment: My mistake, didn't notice that

Comment: Now the only error I am getting is the following: Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute

Comment: Nevermind I found the issue with that problem, now my data is actually inserting my database, thanks for the help.